# Are shallow angle and obtuse angle synonims

Tags: meaning

The title has it: are shallow angle and obtuse angle synonims?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obtuse in the context of angles has a very specific, technical definition (an angle between 90 and 180 degrees). 'Shallow' is subjective and open to interpretation.

I suggest they are not synonyms.